# Tag cleanup [keyboard-shortcuts], [key-bindings], [hotkeys], [shortcut-key]

Tags: discussion, support, tags, synonym-request

tldr: [shortcut-key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/shortcut-key) should be a synonym of [keyboard-shortcuts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/keyboard-shortcuts)

There are currently a lot of tags referring to the same, or almost the same thing:

[keyboard-shortcuts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/keyboard-shortcuts) 113 watchers 4.1k questions, no synonyms

> Keyboard shortcuts provide quick access to application or system actions via combinatorial key presses.

[key-bindings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/key-bindings)  4 watchers 1.3k questions, has 1 synonym: [key-binding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/key-binding)

> Anything related to key-bindings (a.k.a. "keyboard shortcuts",
>   "hotkeys", etc.), i.e. the associations between key combinations and
>   the corresponding actions triggered when the user presses such
>   combinations.

[hotkeys](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/hotkeys) 14 watchers 916 questions, no synonyms

> Hotkeys provide quick access to user interface application or system actions via combinatorial key presses.

[shortcut-key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/shortcut-key) 3 watchers 67 questions, no synonyms

> A keyboard shortcut is a finite set of one or more keys that invoke a software or operating system operation when triggered by the user.

Those tags can have two contexts:

- As a user of the program I want to know the right combination of keys for desired action,
- As a programmer I want to bind some action to a key combination.

What's the right way to disambiguate the context in which the tag is used?
The fact that some shortcuts involve a mouse makes this even more complicated.
I would appreciate some opinions about this.